# What kind of bug/insect is this? photo attached

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This morning (a few hours after sunrise) I saw this insect running over the blanket. 
I'm thinking what it is, if it's a bed bug that missed feeding time and is out of schedule (as i thought that they come out just before sunrise). And I thought they were brown, too but upon research found that they could (colorwise) look similar to this one too. Also, I have not found another one of these and my wife and I both don't find any bite marks on our bodies.  Our matress is packed in a plastic hull to not allow bed bugs to start living in it. What might this be?
Thanks!
[image: placed on my hand when I took the picture and is maybe 3mm long]

Comment: Doesn't look like a bed bug - they have these distinct small heads and this reddish brown oval-shaped abdomen. What it could be is a silverfish nymph (you could tell by the smooth connection between thorax and abdomen) or otherwise something from the order Zygentoma with its filaments missing.

Comment: Do you have any other pictures of the insect?

Comment: I googled pictures of silverfish and it does indeed look like one. The legs especially, both their orientation and count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a doubt we can answer this question with a high level of accuracy: the sample image is very blurred, it is unclear if there are posterior/lower body elements like forceps as well as other significant features which could help with the identification.

My best guess it is baby of Earwig (2000 species): If I look at the posterior part of the body I can "see" the preliminary forceps as well as other similar features, but still the accuracy of the ID is limited.

Enhanced image:

[image]

Baby Earwig:

[image]

Comment: It's an old post that got bumped, but  this is almost definitively not an earwig. Also, FYI: many insects have [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus) on their posterior ends...